# Unable to write to a GPIO pin despite file permissions on /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value

Tags: permissions, sysfs, gpio

This is on a Raspberry Pi.

Here's the output of sudo ls -lL /sys/class/gpio/gpio18:

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 root     gpio     4096 Mar  8 10:50 active_low
-rwxrwx--- 1 root     gpio     4096 Mar  8 10:52 direction
-rwxrwx--- 1 cameron  cameron  4096 Mar  8 10:50 edge
drwxrwx--- 2 root     gpio        0 Mar  8 10:50 power
drwxrwx--- 2 root     gpio        0 Mar  8 10:50 subsystem
-rwxrwx--- 1 root     gpio     4096 Mar  8 10:50 uevent
-rwxrwx--- 1 cameron  cameron  4096 Mar  8 10:50 value
```

So looks like I should now have access to value, great. However:

```
cameron@raspberrypi~ $ echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value
-bash: /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value: Permission denied
```

What's going on? If I chmod 777 everything, then it works, but I shouldn't have to do that when I own the file.

Comment: `/sys` is a pseudo-filesystem and in fact an interface of communication with the kernel. Writing in a file in `/sys` is like making a request to the kernel so that may require permissions which are not expressed by the file attributes.

Comment: And before writing a "1" to `value`, isn't there another file you would have to modify, such as `direction` for example?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14287/cant-read-write-to-gpio-as-non-root-after-export

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding cameron to the gpio group:

```
sudo usermod -aG gpio cameron
gpio export 18 out
echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value
```

Now everything works.

Answer (score 5):

I have not played with the GPIO pins this way but based on lgeorgets *second* comment and [this article](http://falsinsoft.blogspot.ca/2012/11/access-gpio-from-linux-user-space.html), you must first set the direction of the pin to "out".  The `direction` node is owned by root, so:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/direction'
```

`sh -c` is needed here to execute that command in a root subshell.  This is because `sudo echo out > direction` would execute `echo` as root, but the redirection (`> direction`) would be done by your current (non-root) shell. You could also just do this `su root`.

After that you should, hopefully, be able to set `value` as `cameron`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Do you have any suggestions here that will work?  TBH I never use `sudo` (I `su root`) so this was a deduction from the man page and elsewhere.  We probably should have a canonical question about "sudo and redirection", but I am not really the one to ask it since I do not want to bother configuring something I have no use for.

Comment: there is such a question somewhere. Solution would be `sudo sh -c '....'`, `sudo -s` calls the user's shell which we don't know anything about anyway.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thx.  Eek at this tho: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on Which seems to be our canonical one...

Answer (score 1):

As lgeorget mentions as a comment above,

`/sys` is a pseudo file system provided by the kernel, if the kernel requires the writer to be root then this is a fixed requirement by the kernel and can not be changed by fiddling with attributes and owners.

This is explained in more detail with this answer on question : [How to set permissions in /sys/ permanent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70383/31760)  which provides a solution to access such a file using the sudo command, and provides a recipe to modify `/etc/sudoers` to avoid having to type a password in each time.

It really wouldn't make sense to rename any of these files would it ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this file a symbolic link to some other location? Because in that case, the original file may have different ownership than the link.

What are the permissions of the directory (check ls -l one directory up).

Did you change the ownership of this file? Because `sys` is a special virtual filesystem that reflects the internal state of the kernel, so most of these variables are immutable by nature, no matter what the filesystem says.

Comment: Note that the OP used option `-L` in `ls` to dereference the links and show the information on pointed files rather than on symbolic links.

Comment: Who owns the link then?

Comment: There is no link. If you look the output of `ls`, `/sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value` is a regular file. (well... more or less regular, as it's a `/sys` file)

Comment: Then it must be that kernel simply doesn't allow this operation by a regular user. It's convenient to have configuration presented as filesystem (you can use standard tools to manipulate the system on the fly), but never forget that it's not actually a real filesystem.

Comment: I agree. I think glodilocks has pinpointed the problem accurately in his answer.