# Reading system information (/sys/class/dmi/id) without sudo

Tags: linux, sysfs, dmidecode

I am trying to get a unique system identifier. During research I stumbled on the `system serial number` which is exactly what I need (also present on the computer case). 
The serial number is written in the file located in *sysfs*: 
 `/sys/class/dmi/id/product_serial`. 
Executing `ls` shows that the file is read protected and owned by root:

```
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 Mai 29 16:00 product_serial
```

I can't therefore write to it (which is perfect) and I also can't read it without `sudo` which my program cannot be executed under.

If I change the ownership of this file to my user (which is in **sudo** group), then I can read it also with my program without using sudo. But this is overwritten with each reboot.

My question is: can reading of this file (serial number) be done without using `sudo`? Is there perhaps another way to get the serial number that I'm missing?

Is there perhaps a `udev` rules that could change the ownership? I have seen that `hal` existed and did exactly what I'd like, but support what dropped in favor of `udev`. I also thought about reading the information with `sudo` at system startup and saving it somewhere else, but this way the file would then be changeable... Also there is `dmidecode` but also needs `sudo` for accessing this file..

Comment: Do you have `/sys/class/dmi/id/product_sku`?

Comment: BTW, these are just BIOS entries. After reflashing my BIOS with images from the original BIOS maker, my `product_serial` contains `To Be Filled By O.E.M.` ... So if you are a looking for a waterproof way to get a unique system identifier, this is not it. Also, for a certain type of VM, you'd probably get the same value in each VM.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk no, this entry is not there

Comment: @dirkt exactly, those values are read from SMBIOS. I am aware this option is not available for all vendors, but I am using only one vendor which has this entry defined (sample size: ~10, its ok for me :) I would prefer this for identification since this number is also present on the case of the computer so that I can easily match it to the virtual space...

Comment: And see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68897/how-to-set-permissions-in-sys-permanent) for a discussion how to change permissions in `/sys` - TL;DR there doesn't seem to be a canconical way, but there are workarounds. An alternative would be a suid root program which just reads this entry.